# Tracker.autorun behaviour on multiple and nested reactive vars

Tags: meteor

I could not find detailed info on on the behaviour of `Tracker.autorun` in Meteor.

E.g. inside of the autorun function what happens (and why):

- if I get the same reactive var twice
- if I get Meteor.user() and Meteor.userId()
- what about reactive vars got in functions nested inside the autorun function
- what about multiple different reactive vars

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just  edited it.

Comment: Please specify whether you `get` or `set` the variables, not simply `call` them, as the behavior is different. Please add concise code examples and describe any difficulty you come across. It is fairly easy to examine the `Tracker` behavior.

Comment: What MasterAM also pointed is that all of your questions are fairly easily answerable in a few minutes of console tests. Why didn't you run these tests? If you did, did you come across any issue?

Comment: One of the good things SO provides is the possibility to skip "a few minutes of console tests" when a clear answer already exists. I think this question was a good candidate for that.

Comment: @Kyll I was asking myself where the behaviour comes from. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great article about the topic: [Meteor Tracker Manual](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/tracker-manual.md)

The Tracker functions (so called computations) are updated whenever the client is idle (this is called Flush-Cycle). If any reactive variable within a computation did change since the last flush it is rerun. This implies that for my questions 1, 2 & 4 this means the computation is only called once. Even if many different variables are updated.

For the nested function question I wrote a test. As it seems even very deeply nested reactive variables are tracked. So one has to be really careful which functions to call within a Tracker function. Since they may contain reactive vars which are then tracked too.